# Tag page shows lots of empty space

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, new-nav, question-lists

Not sure why, but since today, when I visit the tag page (on Stack Overflow), I see a large empty space at the top of the page.

> [image: empty]

Why is that? Can this be fixed?

---

Browser: Chrome 57.0.2987.133 on Windows

Comment: Do you have an adblocker of any kind that could be doing that? If you do, does turning it off fix that?

Comment: No, I don't have those. I see an ad of Azure next to it.

Comment: That's `<div class="everyonelovesstackoverflow" id="adzerk1112131471"></div>` with `height: 90px`

Comment: But why is that empty without ad blocker? @Pang

Comment: This is not happening for the [combined tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql%20or%20tsql)

Comment: On Meta Stack Overflow: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/346470/persistent-empty-sponsor-section-above-excerpt-in-single-tag-tabs

Comment: The sponsorship has expired, and the space is still there because it's still marked as sponsored. [Related](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161030/is-sponsor-ad-expired-for-excel-tag-if-yes-then-remove-the-free-space)

Comment: @PatrickHofman : [take a look at this too](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/293353/white-empty-space-in-popover-of-points) another white space issue...

Comment: @Sha I doubt it. [This tiny little tag I'd like to moderate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/exact-online) for example hasn't been sponsored for sure.

Comment: Oh my, yeah, it's for all tags. Something is borked.

Comment: @Sha I already explain what ;-) 'tis [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/293315/307988)

Comment: @Cai yeah, but we don't know why it's there for all tags, and it's most likely some bug with sponsored tags.

Comment: Yeh, it's filled with the sponsored ads for sponsored tags, looks like it's always there but just left empty for non-sponsored tags and got overlooked when adding the explicit height

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sorry about that, that was an edge case that slipped by me. I've pushed another fix that should only apply the fixed height to question pages, as the reflow was mainly causing issues there, and not on any of the list pages.

Comment: This change won't fix anything if you have an ad blocker and the ad doesn't load in those spaces though correct? Or asked another way, is it expected now that on question pages, there will be a large amount of whitespace for users with ad blockers?

Comment: This is still broken for me. Even without ad blocker. Page I am visiting: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23

Comment: @MatthewGreen ad block should block those elements entirely. You shouldn't see any difference.

Comment: That's not my experience here: http://imgur.com/wgxPVD8

Comment: Hmm looks like it didn't make it to Prod yet. I'll build that out righ tnow.

Answer (score 6):

It's an empty ad space with an explicit height set...

> [image]

Not sure why it's there (<del>tag pages don't normally have ads do they?</del> I guess it's for sponsored tags, but just left empty for non sponsored tags), but it has [always been there](https://web.archive.org/web/20160405045930/https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css), it was just invisible without the explicit height:

> [image]

Blame [@tripleee](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/289895/307988) and [rossipedia♦](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/293315/307988) for the explicit height.

This should be fixed, but you can work around it for now with some CSS:

```
.everyonelovesstackoverflow { height: auto !important; )
```

Comment: But why is it empty then? I understand there is a div, I already noticed, but it should contain something, right?

Comment: Because I don't think it should be there... probably just no one noticed before because without the explicit height it was empty and invisible

Comment: This answer isn't helpful in any way. I don't 'care' there is a div with an explicit height. When it is there, it should show content. The question is: where is there a div without content?

Comment: Um... I told you what it is and why it's there...

Comment: No, you didn't explain why I am staring at an empty div. It is a bug.

Comment: sure, I agree, I was just saying why the bug was there. as I said, [it's always been there](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lm1Rh.png), but was invisible... it now has an explicit height because of [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/289895/307988)

Comment: Meh. Okay. I still hope it gets fixed and it really isn't as it should be.

Comment: Again, I completely agree... Don't know what the problem is, knowing why the bug exists helps fix that surely?

Comment: I will fix it with a `$('.everyonelovesstackoverflow').hide();` for now.