# White empty space in achievements popover

Tags: bug, achievements-dialog

I receive one upvote for [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/293345/empty-space-in-question-list) so I click on the points and below is what I got in the popver. However I see white space on the top. Not sure for what? Is this a bug or part of the UI?

> [image]

This is how it *should* look like: (taken by a different user)

> [image]

I think below image makes clear why that empty space is logical:

> [image]

However, the summary should only be shown when reputation has been earned on more than one site. If there is only 1 data in that row it is confusing. Two would be clear.

Comment: Uh, are you referring to the space below "Today"? Would you have preferred if it wasn't there? O.o

Answer (score 1):

The whitespace in the achievement dialog is intentional. There it lists your reputation change for each site you have net reputation changes on.

The list starting with the MSE icon at the left with the rep change under it can be quite large for some users. I sometimes have 4 or 5 communities listed there. Even when there is just one, there is nothing bad in terms of UX.

---

After more thinking: The thing that could be a bug here, is that it shows the expanded view for just one account. Could it be you have earned or lost some reputation which got reverted (because of deletion, anything else)?

Comment: No, OP means the +5 is below the site logo, see my edit.

Comment: Yes, that is intentional, right?

Comment: Don't think so, for me there is no such space.

Comment: @Sha you don't see [these](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RezE7.png)?

Comment: @Cai What I was thinking, that expanded view could be shown when having > 1 account rep change. Maybe there is a bug in determining which view to pick.

Comment: @Pat yeh that makes sense, possibly

Comment: this shows both views, so I think you're right: https://i.stack.imgur.com/j5fYD.png

Comment: @Cai only when there is rep change in more than one site. Maybe rep change of 0 cause this bug.