# Ad Blocker Causing Gap

Tags: bug, design, advertising

Apparently, my ad blocker was blocking certain banner ads above the body of questions.

Some examples:
[image: Example 1]
[image: Example 2]

I suggest that the HTML elements should be formatted in a way that automatically aligns everything to the top of that section, so when that image is removed, everything automatically moves up.

An alternative would be to put an image that says something like "Please disable your ad blocker", or anything that makes the page not seem like having a weird gap, positioned directly underneath the ad.

I know I should disable my ad blocker on SE sites (never noticed it was on before this), but that's beside the point here, since I would imagine some other users having an ad blocker on SE sites anyways.

Comment: Relevant: [Why Stack Overflow Doesn’t Care About Ad Blockers](https://stackoverflow.blog/2016/10/26/why-stack-overflow-doesnt-care-about-ad-blockers/)

Comment: So let me get this right. You want a commercial business who makes no money from you to adjust it's product to suit you?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should be able to tell your ad blocker to remove the element, but we're not particularly interested in going out of our way to assist people who choose to use ad block. It's not our intention to annoy you, but it's just like adding your own style tweaks with a browser plugin - feel free, but you're on your own.

We added the placeholder to [reduce page re-flows](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/289895/top-banner-ad-makes-page-jump) and specifically help people who *don't* use ad block. That being said, our external ad server has been a bit inconsistent about actually filling that zone lately, and it's rather frustrating. We're sort of in a "damned if we do; damned if we don't" position at the moment. We'll probably need to switch ad servers to fully correct the problem.

Comment: Ah OK, in that case it wouldn't be something for you to fix then :)

Comment: Both problems could be fixed if ads were just `<img src="/ad.png">`, instead of loading a mile of dubious JavaScript from dubious sources who often try to track your every move across the web.

Answer (score 2):

You've probably got your filter set too tight, or you're just blocking the content itself. Those banner ads are in an iframe in a div, and the outer div has an `id` that starts with "adzerk". If you block that outer element, you'll be able to remove the gap:

[image]

With AdBlock on Chrome, this custom filter takes care of it:

```
##DIV[id^="adzerk"]
```

That'll kill all divs whose id starts with "adzerk", on all sites, everywhere.

Comment: I used `#question>div` in my content filter. Any ETA on when unintended consequences happen?