# It's annoying to click the top banner ad when I'm trying to click upvote

Tags: feature-request, design, advertising

I don't know if my internet is slow, but it seems to be perfectly timed that right when I am about to click the upvote for a question, the top banner ad loads into view right where the upvote button used to be, so that I end up clicking the ad instead. This has happened to me multiple times across the Stack Exchange network.

I plan to click here:

[image]

But the ad jumps in so I click here:

[image]

Thoughts:

- Maybe this is punishing me for my voting style. I upvote if I have the same question as the title.
- Maybe this is a trick to get more ad clicks. (Not really. I hope.)
- [This Q&A](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/289895/top-banner-ad-makes-page-jump) seemed to indicate that a fix had been implemented, but I'm not experiencing that. I guess my feature request is to have a placeholder size for the ad while it is loading. (Or better yet, remove the banner ad.)

Comment: [This is how that invalid Hawaii nuclear launch warning was sent out.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/06Fjp.gif)